# Is the gradient of following polynomial in two variables a local homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, optimization

Let $P(x,y)=x^4+ \lambda x^2y^2 + y^4, \lambda > 0.$ I wonder if $\nabla{P}:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a local homeomorphism for some values of $\lambda > 0$?

I calculated the gradient and hessian first.

$\nabla{P}(x,y)=(4x^3 + 2\lambda xy^2, 2\lambda x^2y + 4y^3). $ If $\lambda$ was $0$, then this'd surely be invertible, but I can't seem to deduce it for $\lambda > 0.$ I write down what I've done so far.

**Calculating the Hessian and its determinant:**

$\nabla^2{P}(x,y)$ is as follows:
\begin{pmatrix}
12x^2 + 2\lambda y^2 & 4\lambda xy \\
4\lambda xy & 12y^2 + 2\lambda x^2
\end{pmatrix}

$det(\nabla^2{P}(x,y))=24\lambda (x^4 + y^4)+ (144-12\lambda^2)x^2y^2.$

From the above, few things are apparent:

(1) When $(x,y)\ne  (0,0)$ and $12\lambda^2 < 144, det(\nabla^2{P}(x,y))\ne 0,$ so $\nabla{P}$ is invertible in a neighborhood of $(x,y).$

(2) When $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ and $12\lambda^2 = 144 \implies \lambda = \sqrt{12},$ then the Hessian is singular, but $\nabla{P}$ can still be invertible. But I can't seem to prove it, either analytically, by computing this inverse or using some other method.

(3) When $(x,y)\ne  (0,0)$ and $12\lambda^2 < 144, det(\nabla^2{P}(x,y))\ne 0$ may not be possible, so inconclusive so far...

(4) $0$ is clearly the unique global minima, so the Hessian must be non-negative definite at $0,$ and indeed here $det(\nabla^2{P}(0,0))=0.$ But this doesn't help us conclude if $\nabla{P}$ is invertible in a neighborhood of zero.

(5) I'd like to use the homogeneity of $P$ in some way, but don't see a direct point of application here.

Comment: Are you sure about (1)? What happens if $144-12\lambda^2<0$ ?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Ah sorry you're absolutely right, in this case, the Hessian can still be zero for some values of $(x,y).$ Editing the OP now!

Comment: If you solve the equation for $t=\frac{x^2}{y^2}$ using $\lambda$ as a parameter it turns out that if $12-\lambda^2<0$ (and $\lambda>0$), then you either obtain a negative discriminant or only negative values of $t$, so it's fine for $12-\lambda^2<0$ as well.

Comment: Same goes for $12-\lambda^2=0$, by the way. I don't know why in (2) you would claim that $24\lambda (x^4+y^4)$ is the determinant of a singular matrix when $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$...

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Oops sorry again, it's clearly wrong, editing the OP now!